# Qt Creator vcpkg integration

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, qt-creator, vcpkg

I'm trying to follow this guide, in order to integrate vcpkg with Qt Creator on Windows 10:
https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-cmake-package-manager-auto-setup
The goal is to use libs from vcpkg inside Qt Creator projects.

Unfortunately `find_package` does not work. With this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TESTvcpkg LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(TESTvcpkg main.cpp)


find_package(wt REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(TESTvcpkg PRIVATE wt::wt)
```

I get this error:

> `8: error: Target "TESTvcpkg" links to target "wt::wt" but the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?`

If I run `vcpkg list` from a command prompt I get the list as expected. So the environment variables should be ok.

The guide talks about `vcpkg.json` file, but is not clear to me where I have to place it; I placed it inside the project folder:

{
"name": "TESTvcpkg",
"version-string": "0.0.1",
"dependencies": [
"wt"
]
}

I have `auto-setup.cmake` inside the project tree of Qt Creator. The last lines are related with vcpkg:

```
#
# vcpkg
#
macro(qtc_auto_setup_vcpkg)
  if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg.json" AND NOT QT_CREATOR_SKIP_VCPKG_SETUP)
    option(QT_CREATOR_SKIP_VCPKG_SETUP "Skip Qt Creator's vcpkg package manager auto-setup" OFF)

    find_program(vcpkg_program vcpkg)
    if (NOT vcpkg_program)
      message(WARNING "Qt Creator: vcpkg executable not found. "
                      "Package manager auto-setup will be skipped. "
                      "To disable this warning set QT_CREATOR_SKIP_VCPKG_SETUP to ON.")
      return()
    endif()
    get_filename_component(vpkg_root ${vcpkg_program} DIRECTORY)

    if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake")
      message(STATUS "Qt Creator: vcpkg package manager auto-setup. "
                     "Skip this step by setting QT_CREATOR_SKIP_VCPKG_SETUP to ON.")

      file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake" "
        set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER \"${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}\")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER \"${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}\")
        ")
      if (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE AND NOT
          CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake")
        file(APPEND "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake"
          "include(\"${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}\")\n")
      endif()

      if (VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET)
        set(vcpkg_triplet ${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET})
      else()
        if (WIN32)
          set(vcpkg_triplet x64-mingw-static)
          if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER MATCHES "cl.exe")
            set(vcpkg_triplet x64-windows)
          endif()
        elseif(APPLE)
          set(vcpkg_triplet x64-osx)
        else()
          set(vcpkg_triplet x64-linux)
        endif()
      endif()

      file(APPEND "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake" "
        set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET ${vcpkg_triplet})
        include(\"${vpkg_root}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake\")
      ")
    endif()

    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vcpkg-dependencies/toolchain.cmake" CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
  endif()
endmacro()
qtc_auto_setup_vcpkg()
```

Is there something I have to change?

To obtain Wt, I've used: `vcpkg install wt:x64-windows` triplet.
The kit in Qt creator uses Microsoft Visual C++ compiler (AMD64)

**EDIT:**
changing these parameters, the example https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-creator-cmake-package-manager-auto-setup seems to work:
[Qt Creator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wythc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The project defines in one of its CMakeLists.txt the target `wt` (see [here](https://github.com/emweb/wt/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L685)). Later in this file it [defines](https://github.com/emweb/wt/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L693) the namespace prefix to `Wt::`. So the target to link with is `Wt::wt`. Case matters when referencing targets in a `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Unfortunately there is something else wrong in my code/configuration. It seems I found a workaround changing some parameters in projects->build->CMake (I'm posting it as EDIT of my main thread)